# Angular build prod in AOT mode

Tags: node.js, angular

So this is really strange.

Local dev environment :
OS : Win x64 
Node version : 8.x (LTS)

The project does not build with the AOT flag. It throws "xyz" does not exist in object of type {}.The fix to this is very obvious.

Remote env:
OS : linux x64
Node version : 6.x (LTS)

The project builds successfully without the above-mentioned compiler errors!

Both environments have the same CLI version. The only difference being the node version, local being higher.

Can anyone shed some light on this? Does the compiler behave differently on node versions higher than 6.x LTS?

Comment: Just an idea, maybe you have local dependencies higher with flag >= versioning and your global package is higher.

Comment: yep that was it. I had a higher compiler version . Thanks !